# Matlab : how to verify if all values of a matrix are part of a list of values

Tags: matlab, compare

I have a 2D matrix ("my_input") and I would like to check if all its values are present in a given list of values (in my case, I want to accept only 0 and 1).
Is there a convenient way to do that ? Here is my "brutal" solution for now :

```
% exclude cases where values are not only 0 and 1
if ~all(all(ismember(my_input,[0 1])))
    return;
end
% rest of the code
```

It's not very simple to read. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you give an example .

Comment: `~all(my_input(:) ==0 | my_input(:) ==1)`?

Comment: ~all(ismember(my_input(:),[0 1]))

Comment: For readability: `all(any(bsxfun(@eq, my_input(:), [0 1]).'))` ... Just kidding :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems no matlab function does the job I was looking for. So I'll go with ASantosRibeiro's solution (which is more versatile since you can easily have several 'accepted' values)

Why did I forget the "(:)" in my code ??
Should I let him

Comment: Sorry should I wait for ASantosRibeiro to post his solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASantosRibeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3651923/asantosribeiro) made the best proposal so far (in comments) :

```
~all(ismember(my_input(:),[0 1]))
```

Although the question was stupid since I almost had the answer, I hope it will help other people in the future.